# Algorithm for computation of infinite sum of polynomial fractions.

Tags: sequences-and-series, algorithms

This is kind of reference request. Let's assume that P(n) and Q(n) are polynomials with integer coefficients.

**Does there exist such an algorithm that computes infinite sums of $P(n)/Q(n)$ if it exists or gives explicit exception when it doesn't exist?**

One can prove that for certain cases sum exists and, for not bigger amount of cases, what it equals to. 
One can use WolframAlpha to find the answer for specific series, but where should I read about some generic algorithm for such series?

There is a similar algorithm for integrals, which allows to factorize polynomial fraction into several more simple fractions and then calculate area of each. We may assume that this step is already done. But this is not applicable to such case $0.5*(1/n - 1/(n+1))$, which is easily computated to 1/2 because the partial sum is $1/2*(1-1/(n+1))$.

p.s. related question: Does exist algorithm that computes partial sums of $P(n)/Q(n)$?
(in some closed form, not just $1/1+1/4+1/9+1/16$)

Comment: These sums exist when $Q(n)$ does not have natural roots and its degree exceeds that of $P$ by at least two units.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I agree that it looks right, but where can I find a proof of this theorem? (I mean why it is a sufficient condition)

Comment: You can prove it by yourself by squeezing with $a/n^2$. It is a necessary and sufficient condition.

Comment: I agree that it is neccessary. But how to prove that it is sufficient condition?

Comment: In the general case, there is no closed-form expression for the partial sums. In particular, the generalized harmonic numbers have no simple expression.

Comment: I just gave you the hint. You also prove divergence when the difference of degrees is too small by comparison with $1/n$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

It is an easy matter to prove
$$\frac{P(n)}{Q(n)}\sim rn^{p-q}$$ where $r$ is the ratio of the leading coefficients and $p,q$ are the degrees. The series converges (diverges) when $p-q\le-2$ (resp. $p-q\ge-1$).

For the series to be defined, $Q$ must also be free of natural roots.

---

In general, closed-form expressions of the partial sums are not available (think of the generalized Harmonic Numbers).

A formula is known for the case of $\zeta(2k)$, via the Bernouilli numbers. Not for $\zeta(2k+1)$.

---

By decomposition of the function in simple fractions, you can make a connection to the Hurwitz zeta function.

Comment: As I understood you, these hints are about convergence. I am sorry for not stressing enough, that question is more about exact values. For example, the input may be an expression 1/n^2 and the output is Pi^2/6. Maybe I want too much and this is too complicated open problem?

Comment: @georgy_d: no, only the first part is about convergence. The result for the Basel sum is implicit in my reference to $\zeta$ for even numbers.